# Firebase Dynamic Links for iOS - Query Parameters are not passed through from iTunes Store

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Hi we are using Dynamic Links on iOS and Android to pass though query parameters for various marketing and share links.  The query parameters are passing through correctly on iOS when a user already has our app installed. However we are not seeing the query parameters come through or the specific dynamic links passed through to us on new iOS app installs that first travel through the iTunes store. We do not have this problem with Android via Google Play.  Is this a known issue with Firebase on iTunes/iOS?

We have debugged our code on our end and are uncertain whether there is something different we need to do in the initialization of our code for brand new installs on iOS?  It is also very difficult to test this out as it requires one to create a brand new production build and do an install from the App Store.  In our testing we are uninstalling the app locally and then reinstalling from the app store. Note that since we have installed the app before, the app store shows a download from Cloud icon as the option even though we are installing the brand new version.  We wonder if this perhaps is the issue?

Any help you can provide in debugging and solving this issue and any tips on how to test without going through the app store would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check you have a custom URL scheme defined for your app (as well as the universal links that you've got working?)

The current way Dynamic Links is working is:

- Store the parameters server side before redirecting to the app store
- On startup, check if its first run. If so, check to see if there are matching server side paramters.
- If there are, call openURL on a custom URL scheme matching your bundle ID (com.foo.bar etc.) and pass the parameters through

So, if the "first open" check is failing it wont do it, or if it can't pass through the parameters (due to missing custom URL scheme).

Comment: " If so, check to see if there are matching server side paramters." Do you know if there is a way to debug or get logs about this part of the process ?
I don't get matches when there is more than 5 minutes between click on the link and the install of the app. I'd like to understand what is happening exactly.

Comment: No easy way to debug unfortunately right now :/ Are you seeing no match at all, or no strong match?

Comment: could you please look at my situation, @IanBarber